# problem with loop

Tags: wp-query

I have problem with this code, whenever I put something after it, it breaks. Is the query closed properly?

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="headdark"><h3>Places nearby <?php echo the_title()?> </h3></div>
<div class="condark relbeach bearound row">

$loclat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'map_lat', true);
$loclng = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'map_lng', true);
$posttype = 'location';
$dist = 10;
$nearbyLocation = get_nearby_loc($loclat, $loclng, $posttype, $dist);
 if ($nearbyLocation):
 global $post;
foreach ($nearbyLocation as $post): 
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="aroundbeach">
<?php 

if((round($post->distance,4) * 1000) > 1000) {
    echo '<div class="distt">'.round($post->distance,2).' KM away'.'</div>';
}else{
 echo '<div class="distt">'.(round($post->distance,2) * 1000).' M away'.'</div>';
}
?></div><div class="thumb">
       <header class="thumb-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_ID()) ?>" class="hover-img">
                <?php
                   $img = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() , array(360,270,'bfi_thumb'=>true)) ;
                   if(!empty($img)){
                       echo balanceTags($img);
                   }else{
                       echo '<img width="360" height="270" alt="no-image" class="wp-post-image" src="'.bfi_thumb(get_template_directory_uri().'/img/no-image.png',array('width'=>360,'height'=>270)) .'">';
                   }
                   ?>
</a></header>
        <div class="thumb-caption">
            <h5 itemprop="name" class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
<div class="text-darken"></div>
            <p class="mb0 text-darken">
            </p></div></div></div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php else : ?>
    <h3 class="center">It seems like there are no places around</h3>
 <?php endif;  ?>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you indent your code? It's super difficult to read and understand, your editor should have auto-indented it for you ( PHPStorm, Sublime Text, Coda, Netbeans, etc )

Comment: Do you have debugging on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missing semicolons on flowing code. i have added semicolons.

```
    <div class="headdark"><h3>Places nearby <?php echo the_title();?> </h3></div>


<header class="thumb-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>" class="hover-img">



<div class="thumb-caption">
            <h5 itemprop="name" class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
```

and

you have used **{}** but in flowing code you use ** : ** in closing logic

```
<?php else : ?
    <h3 class="center">It seems like there are no places around</h3>
 <?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: Shame on me, but simple ";" were the cause. Thank you